# Spring Shell: Execute multiple commands in one line

Tags: java, spring, spring-shell

I have two commands in my Spring Shell application:

```
@ShellComponent
public class HelloCommand {

    @ShellMethod(value = "hello")
    public void hello(){
        System.out.println("hello");
    }

}
```

```
@ShellComponent
public class GoodbyeCommand {

    @ShellMethod(value = "goodbye")
    public void goodbye(){
        System.out.println("goodbye");
    }

}
```

Does Spring Shell support executing both commands in one single line like following:
`shell:>hello && goodbye`
or any other pattern?

I've looked through the Spring Docs but wasn't able to find any information on this.